# I want to assign CustomerId values to AccountId values in a new local variable. How can I do that?

Tags: python-3.x

I am developing my code in dictionaries. I want to assign the values of CustomerId to AccountId in a new local variable(I have to use the new local variable in other places). Is there any method I can do that?

```py
Customer={}
def add_customer():
    while True:
        CustomerId=eval(input("Enter id for customer:"))
        if CustomerId in Customer:
            print("ID already assinged to another customer")
        else:
            CustomerName=(input("Enter customer name:"))
            CustomerCNIC=input("Enter CNIC of customer:")
            CustomerAge=input("Enter age of customer:")
            Customer[CustomerId]=[CustomerName,CustomerCNIC,CustomerAge]
        break
Account={}
def add_account():
    while True:
        AccountId=eval(input("Enter account id:"))
        if AccountId in Account:
            print("ID already assigned to another account holder")
        else:
            AccountType=input("Enter account type:")
            AccountBalance=input("Enter account balance:")
            Account[AccountId]=[AccountType,AccountBalance]
        break
```

Comment: What you are asking for ("assign the values of CustomerId to AccountId in a new local variable") does not make sense to me. Can you explain it in layman's terms?

Comment: What you describe amounts to ˋAccountId = CustomerIdˋ. This does not match how you already define ˋAccountIdˋ in your code. Please clarify what you want to do. Are you looking for something like ˋCustomerAccount[CustomerId] = AccountIdˋ?

Comment: Take note that there is no point in having a ˋwhile True:ˋ loop if you unconditionally ˋbreakˋ out of it. For maintainability, you might want to have a look at classes and namedtuples - your data is inherently structured, which a ˋdict´ does not fully capture.

Comment: I am using while loop because i will use exception hanlding there.

Comment: Imperishable Night: when you go to bank for transaction they ask your customer id and account id if both matches then you are allowed to make transaction. I want to do the same. I want the value at first place of customer id is equal to the ist value of account id.